# Serial Communication support for windows in java

Tags: java, windows, serial-port, rxtx

I need a package for communicating with a electronic console via usb-2-rs232 cable. I got a package called RXTX, but i am not still satisfied with this package. Is there any other alternative for serial communication under windows??

Comment: Why doing hardware windows programming in an OS independent language?

Comment: Why aren't you satisifed with RXTX? What do you need that it doesn't provide?

Answer (score 1):

For Serial Communication we can alos use the Labview software,in his builtin example there is serial communication module.

You can also does serial communication by using hyperterminal.set the default parameters for serial commuinication.

RXTX is also an open source

I would like to recommend you Java Serial Port from serialio.com In java there is java serial API
which you can use